# Trigger a button inside a UpdatePanel with a LoginView

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, triggers, updatepanel

i've an UpdatePanel with a LoginView inside, now, inside the AnonymousTemplate i've a Button (btnLogin), the problem is that the Triggers tag don't see the button.
here is the code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
            <AnonymousTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Iniciar sesión" 
                            onclick="btnLogin_Click" />
            </AnonymousTemplate>
            <LoggedInTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" Text="You're in"/>
            </LoggedInTemplate>
        </asp:LoginView>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnLogin" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And finally the error:
**A control with ID 'btnLogin' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel2'**

Comment: Do you get the error at runtime or during build? If it is runtime do you get the error only when logged in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you might have to do in this case is add the trigger in the code-behind, say, on `Pre_Init` of the page; you can access the `Triggers` property which exposes an `Add` method.

Preempting that you will also need to find the button in the code, too:

```
var button = LoginView1.FindControl("btnLogin") as Button;
```

This ought to do the trick:

```
var trigger = new PostBackTrigger();
trigger.ControlID = button.UnuiqueID;
UpdatePanel2.Triggers.Add(trigger);
```

Comment: Thanks, by the tip, but FindControl didn't find the button, always return null... any ideas?  Otherwise, in the code behind, i didn't see the button :(

Comment: As per Andi's answer - are you logged in at this point, or not? You'll need to determine that to see if it is worth trying to find the button.

Comment: Nop, i'm not logged in. Moreover, i didn't see the TextBox Control in LoggedInTemplate

Comment: I've updated my answer to use `LoginView1.FindControl`, since that is the parent of the button - so it ought to find it. Though, not sure is this container detachment will cause any issues with what could be called a foreign trigger.

Comment: YES! Now works fine! Thank you very much to both. I've changed only one thing PostBackTrigger for AsyncPostBackTrigger.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because the trigger is only valid when your not logged in.

The button doesn't exist once you are logged in.

If you are calling a partial postback on a control within the panel you shouldn't need to use a custom trigger from what I remember.

What happens if you take it out like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
            <AnonymousTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Iniciar sesión" 
                            OnClick="btnLogin_Click" />
            </AnonymousTemplate>
            <LoggedInTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" Text="You're in"/>
            </LoggedInTemplate>
        </asp:LoginView>
    </ContentTemplate>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: The button is in AnonumousTemplate, at the begining must exist, because i'm not logged in... if not... how i can fix this?

Comment: Yes, is a runtime error. But, i can't use btnLogin or txtPassword in code behind, because the VS didn't see too.

Comment: Did it work with no triggers or defining them on the code behind? Glad it's working anyway.