# Postback trigger for button inside a usercontrol in Updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, postback, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a user control placed inside an update panel, ie like this.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="testupdatepnl" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
                        <uc1:TestControl ID="ctlTest" runat="server" />
        </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Now i got a button placed inside this user control say Click. I want to postback the whole page on the button click.
I tried to add a postback trigger like this

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="clickButton" />
</Triggers>
```

Since the button is inside the usercontrol , i got error while running like this.

Is there any way to do a postback for this button.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558049/trigger-a-button-inside-a-updatepanel-with-a-loginview

Comment: @Nalaka526 : but i got an error like 'A control with ID 'ctl00$phContent$ctlList$ctlClientLocations$clickButton' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'testupdatepnl'."

Comment: Can you please send the code you have modified i.e. assigning control's UniqueID serverside as trigger

Answer (score 16):

Remove the `<Triggers>` from HTML & Add this to `PageLoad` event

```
ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(WebUserControl11.FindControl("ButtonId"));
```

**Note :** Learned from [this](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/29004-A-control-with-ID-button-could-not-be-found.aspx)

Comment: But i have another button in the page and want to do a postback on its click, for that button i have added the trigger in the page.

Comment: @mahesh So then keep the trigger in html with the postback trigger for the  Page Button, and add add postback trigger for the UserControl Button on PageLoad. It should work...

Comment: fyi, this worked for me by putting this code in the page_load of the usercontrol itself, which keeps you from having to put usercontrol-specific code in the consumer of a usercontrol.  Thank you so much for the tip though!

Answer (score 0):

Because button you are using as trigger is placed inside update panel and after render its client id gets changed.

Make the button accessable from user control and declare the trigger at server side e.g.

```
var ClickButton= ctlTest.FindControl("clickButton") as Button;


var trigger = new PostBackTrigger();
trigger.ControlID = ClickButton.UniqueID.ToString();
testupdatepnl.Triggers.Add(trigger);
```

See the following thread for more details
[Trigger a button inside a UpdatePanel with a LoginView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558049/trigger-a-button-inside-a-updatepanel-with-a-loginview)

Comment: are you sure you used UniqueID of ClientButton at server side not ClientID?

Answer (score 0):

You should also note that if you are using Ajax Control Toolkit. You can replace ScriptManager to ToolkitScriptManager.

```
Dim btn As Button = CType(UserControl.FindControl("ButtonID"), Button)        
AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(btn)
```